# How do I solve this error in evaluating the argument 'CRSobj'?

Tags: r, raster, elevation, elevatr

Am trying to get elevation raster using elevatr package but I keep getting this "error in evaluating the argument 'CRSobj' in selecting a method for function 'spTransform': NA"

It was originally working in my laptop with the same data but now in my desktop, I keep getting this error. What might have gone wrong?

Comment: in my case a reinstallation of rdgal with install.packages("rgdal", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org") and setting rgdal::set_proj_search_paths("C:/Users/Christof/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/rgdal/proj") as described here github.com/jhollist/elevatr/issues/48#issuecomment-1059802332 had fixed the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with package versions.  Make sure elevatr, raster, rgdal, and sp are up-to-date.  Lot of changes have happened in the last year or so around PROJ and this has cascaded through all of the spatial packages.